# count program using hash table and chaining

Tags: chaining

This assignment is designed to use a hash table to count the number of unique addresses accessed
by a program. You need to implement a program called count. The input of the count program
is a trace consisting of 64-bit addresses and you are required to print out the number of unique
address in the trace. This needs to be implemented using a hash table and chaining. I don't know how to begin. I was thinking using linked list that test if the item is already stored in the list or not, making all of the items in the linked list "unique addresses". Any help  with the coding would be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

yeah you are on the right track, i am assuming this is in C. I would implement hash key function, insert function with linked list and possibly a counts functions and you should be good to go.